# Conversion not showing up in Adwords on Angular 6 App

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

Im trying to fire Google conversions from my Angular 6 app. Google Tag Assistant shows that its working on localhost but when I check conversions on Google Ads (where the code came from) .... nothing. Ive waited some time as well.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'XXXXXX');
</script>


<!-- Event snippet for Website Visit conversion page -->
<script>
    gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': 'XXXXXX',
        'value': 11.0,
        'currency': 'USD'
    });
  </script>
```

Which ive tried in the index.html file (in head) and also created after the view loaded in the angular.component.ts file which you can see below :

```
runGTMScript() {
    console.log(this.company);
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.async = true;
    s.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-XXXXXXXX"
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
    var s2 = document.createElement("script");
    s2.type = "text/javascript";
    s2.innerHTML = `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'AW-XXXXXXX');`
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s2);
    if (typeof gtag != 'undefined') {
        console.log('GTAG Loaded');
    }

}
```

Here are screenshots showing the action ...

[image]

[image]

I cant seem to figure out the issue. I could understand if the tag manager wasnt catching the fired tags but it is .... Could it be because Im using localhost?

Comment: In your tag assistant I dont see google tag manager. This might be the reason

Comment: Is that not the Global Site tag?

Comment: those 3 items in your Tag Assisntant are all from Google Ads. Google Tag Manager starts with GTM-....

Comment: Yea, Google Ads is where the code from Google Conversions can come from. Either that or GTM.